# What do you call someone who acts "cool-headed"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, epithet-requests

I mean someone who acts regardless of his/her feelings, according to what's the best option. I mean tough choices where your brain dictates something but your feelings might say something else.

I'm looking for an adjective that describes a character in a story. The woman leaves her twin baby daughters in a roadside in China because they had better chances of surviving there than if she carried them along - we're talking during the Japan invasion of China.

Comment: I'm looking for an adjective that describes a character in a story. The woman leaves her twin baby daughters in a roadside in China because they had better chances of surviving there than if she carried them along - we're talking during the Japan invasion of China.

Comment: I'd recommend adding a sample sentence and the 'single-word-request' tag, so your question reaches better-suited users

Comment: Level-headed.  But hold on, that sounds like the plot of the Joy Luck Club by Amy Tan.

Comment: I can't answer due to rep limit, but [unflappable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unflappable) seems apt to me.

Comment: So, er, you want an adjective that means "cool-headed". What's wrong with... "cool-headed"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby ‘Cool-headed’ doesn't fit the requirement in my opinion.  It usually means avoiding panic in the presence of an *immediate* threat.  The threat to the children is not so immediate.

Comment: The best I can do is ‘grimly realistic’.  Maybe I'll think of a single word later.  None of those yet suggested convey the connotation of a painful choice.  ‘Unemotional’?  For all we know, she screamed curses at heaven as she turned her back on her babies.

Answer (score 19):

I'd go with **pragmatic**. Since you mentioned "someone who acts regardless of his/her feelings, according to what's the best option", pragmatic seems fitting. Though a pragmatic person needn't always cast aside his/her feelings.

In the situation that you've mentioned,

> [A] woman leaves her twin baby daughters in a roadside in China because they had better chances of surviving there than if she carried them along.

the woman can be described as being "rational".

Someone who is **rational** chooses the best possible way out of a problem. Wikipedia explains *rationality* as:

> the quality or state of being reasonable, based on facts or reason. Rationality implies the conformity of one's beliefs with one's reasons to believe, or of one's actions with one's reasons for action.

**Unsentimental** can also be used.

> Unsentimental
>
> - facing facts or difficulties realistically and with determination
> - not tending to indulge the emotions excessively

Comment: Also perhaps "unemotional" in a decision making context.

Answer (score 11):

Several suggestions:

[Dispassionate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dispassionate)

> not influenced or affected by emotions

[Calculating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/calculating)

> marked by prudent analysis or by shrewd consideration of self-interest

Answer (score 6):

A **Stoic**, from the philosophy of Stoicism, is someone who tries to be indifferent to external things and bases their decisions on reason rather than emotion. I think the terms **logical** or **rationalist** apply here as well.

Also the fictional character Spock in Star Trek is a really good archetype, he was a Vulcan and *"they are noted for their attempt to live by logic and reason with no interference from emotion"* [Vulcan on Wikipedia]

Comment: Ah, just beat me to *stoic*. I'll pull it from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, about that.:) I was surprised that the word stoic wasn't an answer yet

Answer (score 6):

*Stolid* comes to mind:

[Stolid](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stolid):

> Calm, dependable, and showing little emotion or animation

Often used to describe heroic figures standing firmly in the face of danger, unwavering while normal folk might cower or flee.

For that matter, you might also want to consider *unwavering*.

[Unwavering](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unwavering):

> Not wavering; steady or resolute

Answer (score 3):

You could say that she has **[ice (water) in her veins](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Ice%20in%20your%20veins)**. This term is typically applied to sports situations where a player is under extreme pressure and acts cool-headed, but I think it might work well in the situation you describe.

For example, from a [news report](http://floridastate.247sports.com/Bolt/FSU-kicker-Ricky-Aguayo-has-ice-water-in-his-veins-47251674):

> Florida State kicker Ricky Aguayo has ice water in his veins and he made sure to let everyone know about it after connecting on a 40-yard field goal in the fourth quarter against Ole Miss to extend the Seminoles' lead.

Comment: Ice is correct theme. Quote from Top Gun, "You wanted to know who the best is? That's him. Iceman. He flies ice-cold. No mistakes." The character is a contrast to the emotional Maverick character.

Answer (score 3):

***Calm and collected***, or just ***collected***. According to [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/collected), *collected* means "calm and self-controlled."

> ‘The captain, surely a typically calm and collected Norwegian, knows
>   that some of the refugees will commit suicide if he turns towards
>   Indonesia.’
>
> ‘Nevertheless, a cool, calm and collected Michael started the engine,
>   grabbed a gear and shot off down the road.’

Answer (score 2):

I would say *[selfless](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/selfless)* - Concerned more with the needs and wishes of others than with one's own

Answer (score 2):

The word that came to mind for me is [*objective*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/objective).

> Based on facts rather than feelings or opinions; not influenced by feelings.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about `dispassionate` (mentioned elsewhere), but that doesn't quite seem to cover this.  It seems like there would be HUGE amounts of passions involved.

How about [sangfroid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sangfroid)?

> self-possession or imperturbability especially under strain

or

> the ability to stay calm in difficult or dangerous situations

Answer (score 0):

How about

Sedate:

> (a.)  Undisturbed by passion or caprice; calm; tranquil; serene; not
>   passionate or giddy; composed; staid; as, a sedate soul, mind, or
>   temper

Or its synonym, Staid:

> (a.)  Sober; grave; steady; sedate; composed; regular; not wild,
>   volatile, or fanciful.

Answer (score 0):

**equanimous**

> having or showing [equanimity](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equanimity); even-tempered:
>
> *It was difficult to remain equanimous in the face of such impertinence.*

from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equanimous

where *equanimity* means

> mental or emotional stability or composure, especially under tension or strain; calmness; equilibrium.

from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/equanimity

Also see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equanimity).

Answer (score 0):

Both "**self-sacrificing**" and "**sacrificial**" seem to fit very well.
Sacrifice contains the images of value to giver and recipient and loss and in this case certainly grief and sorrow on the part of the mother.

"Selfless" is good  (mungflesh got there first)

Self-deprecating / effacing

With an eye to the future.
With an eye to the greater good.

**More general:**

Measured

Nerves of ice.

Nerves of steel.

A steady hand on the tiller (or wheel)

Cool under fire.

A handy (wo)man in a storm / fray / emergency ...

---

"Even tempered" - Diamond python beat me to it.

"Self-controlled" - but Juan beat me to it :-)